# Strip info from the URL - PHP / htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am hosting a chatroom, and here is a potential link:
website.com/room.php?roomName=blabla

I would like my users to join this above chatroom by simply going to website.com/blabla

How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, just take the whole URL path and rewrite it into the query string.  The value will be available to your PHP scripts in `$_GET['roomName']`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /room.php?roomName=$1
```

The `RewriteCond` lines are checking to make sure the URL does not point at an actual file/directory (otherwise, you would not be able to access such files/directories).

If this isn't what you want, please explain your goals further.

Comment: Awesome, that's the logics I was thinking about :) Just to make sure: website.com/(anything), the anything here, if not an existing folder/file, will be the roomName GET value?

Comment: And, should I put [R=301,L] after the RewriteRule?

Comment: `R=301` will make it a hard redirect (i.e., it will instruct the client to make a new request), thus causing your rewritten URL to appear in the user's address bar.  I don't _think_ that's what you want.  As for `L`, it would depend on whether you want to proceed with (or avoid) further rewrites.  If this is your only rule, there's no need (but it wouldn't hurt anything, either).

Comment: sure, lmk if you have any issues

Answer (score 0):

In your Root folder,create .htaccess file that contains this :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^/room.php?roomName=(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Only links that begin with Website/room.php?roomName=xxx will be redirected to Website/xxxx,so files and folders are preserved.